# creating and using static attributes in service

Tags: angular2-services

I have a service , that open a dialog .
In that service I  have attributes that I would like to share between all app users . 
If I declare them static in my service and use them as follow :

```
    @Injectable()
export class DialogsService {



    static descriptionOptions :Array<string> =[ "Contains", "Begins with" ,"End with" ,"Equals" ];

    constructor(private dialog: MdDialog , private cuntryService :CountryService ,
     private mpMaterialService :MPMaterialService ) {
        ....
     }
   public openMyDialog(  ) 
    {
        let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MyDialog>;
        dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialog , 
                      {  height: '450px',  width: '450px'});// define dialog size

        dialogRef.componentInstance.descriptionOptions = DialogsService.descriptionOptions;

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe ( (response) => .....{ }  );
   }

}


@Component({
    selector: 'MyDialog -dialog',
    templateUrl: './MyDialog -dialog.html',
    styleUrls: ['./MyDialog -dialog.css']

})
export class MyDialog {

    descriptionOptions  :Array<string>;

    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<MyDialog>) 
    {
        console.log("MyDialog constructor");

    }

    closeDialog(  ) {
        this.dialogRef.close('return result');

}
}
```

does the static deceleration for descriptionOptions make the attribute be created only once for all the app users ?

Comment: Is your service provided at feature module level or app module level ? Does your service has multiple instances or the default singleton service it is ?

Comment: DialogsService  is provided at app module level  ,  as singleton

Comment: then no need to declare them static , if it is a singleton class then u can just set the properties of the service from somewhere and get the value from any component/service you wish .